# how can i retrieve values from xml in php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a simple xml string and store into arrays..

i want the information put into a array so i can get it from an index somehow, can anyone help me?

this is what I'm trying so far:

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Person.search/en/xml/e72f8f2f685df4dad86f939097d14f36/Brad+Pitt");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string); 


foreach($xml->children()->children()->children() as $child)
{
    if ($child->getName() == "images")
        echo $child[0];
}

$error_code = (string)$body[0]->Response->return->error_code;
print_r($error_code); 
?>
```

this is the xml response:

```
<OpenSearchDescription><opensearch:Query searchTerms="brad+pitt"/><opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults><people><person><score>1</score><popularity>3</popularity><name>Brad Pitt</name><id>287</id><biography>From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia. William Bradley "Brad" Pitt (born December 18, 1963) is an American actor and film producer. Pitt has received two Academy Award nominations and four Golden Globe Award nominations, winning one. He has been described as one of the world's most attractive men, a label for which he has received substantial media attention. Pitt began his acting career with television guest appearances, including a role on the CBS prime-time soap opera Dallas in 1987. He later gained recognition as the cowboy hitchhiker who seduces Geena Davis's character in the 1991 road movie Thelma & Louise. Pitt's first leading roles in big-budget productions came with A River Runs Through It (1992) and Interview with the Vampire (1994). He was cast opposite Anthony Hopkins in the 1994 drama Legends of the Fall, which earned him his first Golden Globe nomination. In 1995 he gave critically acclaimed performances in the crime thriller Seven and the science fiction film 12 Monkeys, the latter securing him a Golden Globe Award for Best Supporting Actor and an Academy Award nomination. Four years later, in 1999, Pitt starred in the cult hit Fight Club. He then starred in the major international hit as Rusty Ryan in Ocean's Eleven (2001) and its sequels, Ocean's Twelve (2004) and Ocean's Thirteen (2007). His greatest commercial successes have been Troy (2004) and Mr. & Mrs. Smith (2005). Pitt received his second Academy Award nomination for his title role performance in the 2008 film The Curious Case of Benjamin Button. Following a high-profile relationship with actress Gwyneth Paltrow, Pitt was married to actress Jennifer Aniston for five years. Pitt lives with actress Angelina Jolie in a relationship that has generated wide publicity. He and Jolie have six children—Maddox, Pax, Zahara, Shiloh, Knox, and Vivienne. Since beginning his relationship with Jolie, he has become increasingly involved in social issues both in the United States and internationally. Pitt owns a production company named Plan B Entertainment, whose productions include the 2007 Academy Award winning Best Picture, The Departed. Description above from the Wikipedia article Brad Pitt, licensed under CC-BY-SA, full list of contributors on Wikipedia.</biography><url>http://www.themoviedb.org/person/287</url><images><image type="profile" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w45/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg" size="thumb" width="45" height="68" id="4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"/><image type="profile" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg" size="profile" width="185" height="281" id="4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"/><image type="profile" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/h632/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg" size="h632" width="416" height="632" id="4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"/><image type="profile" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg" size="original" width="1295" height="1969" id="4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"/></images><version>685</version><last_modified_at>2013-07-26 18:18:17 UTC</last_modified_at></person></people></OpenSearchDescription>
```

thanks, help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Person.search/en/xml/e72f8f2f685df4dad86f939097d14f36/Brad+Pitt");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string); 


foreach($xml->people->person->images->image as $child){
    $node = (array)$child;
    print_r($node);
    echo $node['@attributes']['url'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml->people->person->images->image); 
exit;
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleXML extension provides is a simple way of getting an XML element's name and text.

Compared to DOM or the Expat parser, SimpleXML just takes a few lines of code to read text data from an XML element.

SimpleXML converts the XML document (or XML string) into an object, like this:

Elements are converted to single attributes of the SimpleXMLElement object. When there's more than one element on one level, they are placed inside an array
Attributes are accessed using associative arrays, where an index corresponds to the attribute name
Text inside elements is converted to strings. If an element has more than one text node, they will be arranged in the order they are found
For more info visit:
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have been used function that work fine for me.

Have you tried this one?

http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/